# Where is the destructor called?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, destructor

I'm learning C++ and want to use objects in classes. The output of my program confuses me, because I expected, that the data destructor would be called two times. My object is created with "Data data(3);" and it's destructor should be called at the end of the code block and also when the rects destructor is called, the destructor of data inside the rect should be called too. As I expected it prints "data destructor" two times after the code block ends. But it also prints it, after my data object is created. Why does this happen and how can I delete the allocated memory inside of data correctly?

```
class Data {
private:
    int* data;
    int size;
public:
    Data() {
        size = 10;
        data = new int[size];
    }
    Data(int size)
        : size(size) {
        data = new int[size];
    }
    virtual ~Data() {
        // delete data;
        std::cout << "data destruktor" << std::endl;
    }
    void init(int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            data[i] = val;
    }
    int& operator[](int index) {
        return data[index];
    }
    int getSize() const {
        return size;
    }
};

class Rect {
private:
    Data data;
    int width, height;
public:
    Rect() {}
    Rect(int width, int height, Data data, int val = 0)
        : width(width), height(height), data(data) {
        data.init(val);
    }
    int getWidth() const {
        return width;
    }
    int getHeight() const {
        return height;
    }
    int getArea() const {
        return width * height;
    }
    Data& getData() {
        return data;
    }
};

int main() {

    {
        Data data(3);
        std::cout << "data created" << std::endl;
        Rect rect(5, 4, data, 9);
        std::cout << "end of code block" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "end of program" << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
data created
data destruktor
end of code block
data destruktor
data destruktor
end of program
```

Comment: Re "But it also prints it, after my data object is created. ", you're passing a `Data` by value. That creates a temporary object. Which is destroyed. Everything works just as it should, and there's nothing to worry about except the advice that lured you into defining an `init` member function. Just don't do that, and place the source of that advice in a "very suspect, doubt that person's statements by default" category. Oh, sorry, I didn't see: you **lack a copy constructor**. That makes you `delete` an array twice. Undefined behavior. Use `std::vector` instead!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Function parameters aren't temporary objects

Comment: When you construct the Rect object, you are passing in the 'data' variable by value.  This will create a copy of that object which will be destructed after the return from the Rect constructor.  I think that's the one that's causing the confusion.

Comment: @M.M. I'm sorry but what you're saying here, " Function parameters aren't temporary objects", is meaningless to me even with a very generous positive interpretation of what you might mean by "parameters". I.e., nonsense. Just to put this to the point, are you contesting (a) that there is an object, or (b) that it is temporary. If the latter, what do you think the lifetime of that object is?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The object defined by `Data data` (in the function parameter list) has automatic storage duration and its lifetime is the lifetime of the function call.  It has the same storage and end-of-life as a variable declared inside the function body would have (although it starts slightly earlier).  Temporary objects are not declared; they are created by prvalue expressions.

Comment: @M.M. Seems like you're claiming that the object is not temporary, *and* you say that its lifetime is restricted to the function call. That's **very temporary** to me: existing only within an expression. I understand where you're coming from: you're thinking that it's natural to assume the standard's half-formal definition of the term was intended in my comment to the newbie. Do you see the insanity in that?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "temporary object" is a formal term in C++ , which does not include automatic objects. [See here for description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)

Comment: @M.M. Notice that I've already mentioned that (except that I described it as half-formal, because there's no formal definition: those are italicized, if you want to look for it). Apparently you were unable to see that I said what you say here, in the very comment you're responding to. As you're unable to see the complete irrelevance and near insanity of bringing that POV to a descriptive term.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing the c'tor of the Rect a copy of Data, which is destroyed after the constructor call and thus is your desctructor call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect(int width, int height, Data data, int val = 0)
```

You are passing `Data` by value here, so a new one gets created and destroyed when you call this method. It should be:

```
Rect(int width, int height, Data &data, int val = 0)
```

or possibly even `const Data &data`: it isn't clear why you're passing a `Data` when `Rect` already has one of its own. Maybe you shoudl be copy-assigning it, or copy-constructing it:

```
Rect(int width, int height, const Data &data, int val = 0)
: data(data)
// ...
```

NB You do need the `delete data;` line,actually as `delete[] data;` as pointed out by @P0W. And the copy constructor for `Data::Data(const Data&)` as well.

Comment: The other issue is missing copy-constructor which results in twice deletion and potentially a crash/UB. Also the delete should be `delete [] data;`